# order_products column connected with Google Checkout transaction in osCommerce

Tags: php, google-checkout, oscommerce

I am using Google Checkout with osCommerce and want to know which column of the `order_products` database table is connected with the transaction.

Google Checkout displays the price details of every product and I want to know from where in the code this detail comes from.

Answer (score 0):

In osCommerce the payment modules have a method called `process_button()`.

This method draws a form with the hidden fields the payment method needs. In the case of Google Checkout it will draw the fields needed by Google to show the information.

You can check in `catalog/includes/modules/payment/<your Google Checkout module>.php` that function to see which fields are sent to Google Checkout to show the information.